# Keep in select mode untill entering text in uitextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two text fields in uitableviewcell and i have selected one cell and i have to keep that cell in selected state untill enter a text i dont want to allow to go cursor nextfield withot entering a text thanks in advance

```
[self.playerTable.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx,BOOL*stop)
     {  //UITableViewCell *cell = obj;
         UITableViewCell *cell1 = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

         if([cell1 isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
         {
             for(UITextField *textField in cell1.contentView.subviews)
             {
                 [textField resignFirstResponder];
                 if([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                 {
                     textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                     [textField resignFirstResponder];
                 }

             }

         }
     } ];
```

Comment: can you explain what problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: From above code we can see that you are resigning text field without any condition, can you put some condition like if textfield's text length is 0 than don't resign ?

Comment: i have taken uitextfield in uitableview cell in edit mode i have entering text in all cells if i enterd text in one cell which is alredy existed in other cell okay in that time if click on other textfield i wont allow to go cursor to next textfield cursor and as well selection has to stay in current text field

Comment: No if i click another text field keyboard has to be resign but selection mode cursor has to be stay on that text field

Comment: can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521839/do-not-pass-cursor-to-next-textfield-without-entering-value-in-first-textfield?noredirect=1#comment32498526_21521839

Comment: to better understanding my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the textfield delegate method to find out it

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

        if (secondTextField == textField && [[firstTextField text] length]==0) {
            //No text on first text field
            [firstTextField becomeFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }

        if (secondTextField == textField && [[secondTextField text] isEqualToString:[firstTextField text]]) {
            // Same text
            [firstTextField becomeFirstResponder];
            return NO;

        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: but when i enter same text which is alredy existed in another text field only it has to be happan vijay

Comment: "it has to be happan" means?

Comment: means until entering differnt text that current textfield has to be in select mode and cursor has to be wait on selected textfield